# want to use one jquery tag into two elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have two input type text, and i have a one jquery selector #tags which now i can use only for one element i want to use it for both.

```
<form method="get" action="search.php">
<input type="text" name="search_text" class="h_input_one" placeholder="Type Here">
<input type="text" name="s_city" class="h_input_two" id="tags" placeholder="Select City">
<input type="submit" class="sub" value="">
    </form>
```

2nd Code

```
    <form method="get" action="/city">
<input type="text" name="city" class="h_input_three"  id="tags"  placeholder="Select City">
<input type="submit" class="sub" value="">
        </form>
```

you can see tags are same in both. and my jquery code is

jQuery(function($) {

```
$("a.topopup").hover(function() {
        loading(); // loading
        setTimeout(function(){ // then show popup, deley in .5 second
            loadPopup(); // function show popup 
        }, 1); // .5 second
return false;
});

/* event for close the popup */
$("div.close").hover(
                function() {
                    $('span.ecs_tooltip').show();
                },
                function () {
                    $('span.ecs_tooltip').hide();
                }
            );

$("div.close").click(function() {
    disablePopup();  // function close pop up
});

$(this).keyup(function(event) {
    if (event.which == 27) { // 27 is 'Ecs' in the keyboard
        disablePopup();  // function close pop up
    }   
});

$("div#backgroundPopup").click(function() {
    disablePopup();  // function close pop up
});

$('a.livebox').click(function() {
    alert('Hello World!');
return false;
});


 /************** start: functions. **************/
function loading() {
    $("div.loader").show();  
}
function closeloading() {
    $("div.loader").fadeOut('normal');  
}

var popupStatus = 0; // set value

function loadPopup() { 
    if(popupStatus == 0) { // if value is 0, show popup
        closeloading(); // fadeout loading
        $("#toPopup").fadeIn(0500); // fadein popup div
        $("#backgroundPopup").css("opacity", "0.7"); // css opacity, supports IE7, IE8
        $("#backgroundPopup").fadeIn(0001); 
        popupStatus = 1; // and set value to 1
    }   
}

function disablePopup() {
    if(popupStatus == 1) { // if value is 1, close popup
        $("#toPopup").fadeOut("normal");  
        $("#backgroundPopup").fadeOut("normal");  
        popupStatus = 0;  // and set value to 0
    }
}
/************** end: functions. **************/
```

}); // jQuery End

Comment: _"i have two input type text, and i have a one jquery selector #tags which now i can use only for one element i want to use it for both"_ Where is selector `#tags` used at `js` at Question?

Comment: Use 'class' instead of 'ID' if you want multiple elements to be identified under same category. Plus I don't see anywhere where u have referenced the id `tag` in ur code.

Comment: i called #tags in type=text" two times,

Comment: @HarisFaraz `id` of element should be unique in `document`

Comment: This is my question, what should i do. My only purpose is that both input will use my jquery code, suggest me how can i achieve it?

Comment: it will be your favor, please rectify my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a variable referencing `input` elements having `class` attributes with values set to `h_input_two` , `h_input_three`; use existing `html` after removing duplicate `id` `id="tag"` at `<input>` elements

```
<form method="get" action="search.php">
  <input type="text" name="search_text" class="h_input_one"   
    placeholder="Type Here">
  <input type="text" name="s_city" class="h_input_two" 
    placeholder="Select City">
  <input type="submit" class="sub" value="">
</form>
<form method="get" action="/city">
  <input type="text" name="city" class="h_input_three"  
    placeholder="Select City">
  <input type="submit" class="sub" value="">
 </form>
```

[`Element.id`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/id) should be unique in `document`.

```
var inputs = $("input[class=h_input_two],input[class=h_input_three]")
```

Comment: Thank you Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

`id` selector returns the first match. Add a common class to the elements and use a class selector like `$('.commonClass')` instead.